# One tabular with column input from multiple data files with pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, input, multiple-files

I have a question which sort of extends the page [Multiple Files input to one pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10284/multiple-files-input-to-one-pgfplotstable).

In the answer to this question, data is read from `dataB.dat` and subsequently appended to the data as described in `dataA.dat`.

I want to be able to take arbitrary columns from both `dataA.dat` and `dataB.dat` and create a new tabular with that data, instead of appending.

I looked in the `pgfplotstable manual Revision 1.9 (2013/10/03)` at `section 4`, but I can't to seem to solve the problem.

A minimal working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstablenew[]{3}{\dataC}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={dataA.dat}{[index]0}]{par1}{\dataC}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={dataB.dat}{[index]0}]{par2}{\dataC}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset
    [
        columns={par1,par2},
        columns/par1/.style=
        {
            column name=test1,
            sci,
            sci 10^e,
            precision=5,
        },
        columns/par2/.style=
        {
            column name=test2,
            sci,
            sci 10^e,
            precision=5,
        },      
    ]
    {\dataC}
\end{document}
```

It works, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Is it?

Comment: you are not typesetting the first column as it is not in the list given to `columns`

Comment: @percusse Indeed. Thanks for the advice, I fixed the minimal working exmaple. But is this the correct way to do it? Or is there a better, perhaps neater, way?

Comment: You can provide the common options directly which would apply to all columns. Other than that it's pretty neat :)